# How to reverse hash string, using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, pycrypto, hashlib

I have hashed email Ids and I want to implement some process so that I can reverse hash string.
I just tried this approach using python hashlib and pycrypto modules, but unfortunately I failed , and also I read many posts on the same topic but none worked for me and fortunately I found something on google which says it do decrypt and encrypt which isn't true in case of HASHING, but it does the job. URL is https://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha256.
 
I was wondering how this website manage to do that.

Using hashlib I get

```
import hashlib
hashlib.sha256("mishraamrish.asm@gmail.com".encode())
<sha256 HASH object @ 0x7f55e30c3b20>
_.hexdigest()
'3ad0c9ce5b036587d08b4a13e7478ea4472ec32de04854bc37dcfed1baf760cc'
```

and from that website when i opted out for Encrypt I got

```
Sha256(mishraamrish.asm@gmail.com) = 3ad0c9ce5b036587d08b4a13e7478ea4472ec32de04854bc37dcfed1baf760cc
```

similarly when I used Decrypt option i got

```
3ad0c9ce5b036587d08b4a13e7478ea4472ec32de04854bc37dcfed1baf760cc : mishraamrish.asm@gmail.com
```

so its a kind request from one who is willing to down vote. please analyse it before going ahead with down vote button.

I know hashing isn't reversible process, and I am curious about that website, if its not then how they are doing it?

Thank You.

Comment: Encryption is reversible. Hashing is not.

Comment: If hashes were reversible, they would not be useful. According to the information on the website you linked, it has a big database of computed hashes that it can look them up in. But given a hash it hasn't previously found, it cannot reverse it.

Comment: Input for md5 has arbitrary length, output is fixed length. Ergo, multiple inputs WILL hash to the same output. Therefore, inverse operations are not possible.

Comment: Guyzz please visit the website i have mentioned above and do compare with haslib results and lastly if not possible then how that website does it?

Comment: Did you read the page? It clearly says how it does it: by precalculating hashes of billions of strings and storing them in a database, then comparing input. Make an unlikely string that it probably hasn't ever seen before (e.g. `"last Wednesday's schnitzel"`), make a SHA2 hash somewhere other than that database (e.g. `"dbef13ba1bdc76bd006f4dc7bec86c7968470ef8e7519033964132e56eb4efd8"`), and see how well the "decryption" works.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you nice approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

So what you want is to get the original string from a hash? The main reason we use hashes is that they are non-reversible, so I don't think that's possible. You may got confused with **encryption**, which can **decrypted** using a key.

Sorry I can't be more helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Cryptographic hash functions like SHA2, SHA3, Shake, Blake2, etc. are all one-way functions. They can hash arbitrary length inputs to a fixed size like 256 in SHA-256. Due to the pigeon principle, there are **collisions** and they are **inevitable**. But we expect to find if hard. We expect them to have;

- **preimage-resistance** — for essentially all pre-specified outputs, it is computationally infeasible to find any input which hashes to that output, i.e., to find any preimage `x'` such that `h(x') = y` when given any y for which a corresponding input is not known.
- **2nd-preimage resistance, weak-collision** — it is computationally infeasible to find any second input which has the same output as any specified input, i.e., given `x`, to find a 2nd-preimage `x' != x` such that `h(x) = h(x')`.
- **collision resistance, strong-collision** — it is computationally infeasible to find any two distinct inputs `x`, `x'` which hash to the same output, i.e., such that `h(x) = h(x')`.

In your case, it is the pre-image attack. Generic pre-image attacks on cryptographic hash functions have `O(2^x)`-time complexity where `x` is the output length of the hash function. In SHA-256 `O(2^256)`

The web site you have mentioned **has a trick**, then you want to SHA256 hash some text, they immediately store it on their database. When you asked about the hash value that you got from their site, they search for it on their database. It exists since they store it when you asked the hash value. So, you helped them to increase the hashes of their DB. They only have `6,128,202,407 sha256 hash database` which is a tiny amount compared to possible outputs od SHA-256 that is `2^256`

**Side note:** hashing is not encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot find a unique mapping from a hashing and the data it was generated to, you can still maintain a database describing mappings between certain data and their hash.
By doing a reverse research on the hash, you can find instances of data that would produce the particular hash you are looking for (if you get a match in your database).

Of course the database could have no match or contain multiple matches of the [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), because of the mathematical definition of a hash as being **unilateral**.

That is exactly how sites such as the one you provided work.

It is also the same mechanism used in [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).